# Is it possible to create a view/function which can access and combine data across Kusto clusters rather than using cross cluster query?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

We have `logs` table defined in 2 different clusters(different regions), the ask is to create a view or a table that can provide a combined data view.

I can do it using cross-cluster `union` query like the below, however, would like to know if we can somehow use a similar query to create a view/function which will provide combined data.

```
logs|
union withsource=SourceTable cluster('\*\*\*\*.kusto.windows.net').database('****').table('logs')
```

Comment: Have you tried something and/or read the relevant documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/cross-cluster-or-database-queries?pivots=azuredataexplorer

Comment: Thanks! I'm able to create a function, somehow earlier I was getting syntax error as i guess now cluster was not getting recognized and thought this kind of function creation is not allowed in Kusto.                                                                           
`.create function
with (docstring = 'Demo function', folder='Demo',skipvalidation = "true")
logs_vw(){  logs|
union withsource=SourceTable cluster('\*\*\*\*.kusto.windows.net').database('****').table('logs')  }`

Answer (score 0):

We can create a function and syntax below -

```
.create function with (docstring = 'Demo function', folder='Demo',skipvalidation = "true") logs_vw(){  logs| union withsource=SourceTable cluster('\*\*\*\*.kusto.windows.net').database('****').table('logs')  }
```

Verified data count -

```
logs_vw
| count;
```